# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(String, String) from the type Map<String,Map<String,String>>

Tags: map, string, duplicate-value

Below code throws this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(String, String) from the type `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`

Code:

```
//I have this map
Map <String,Map <String,String>> MapFist= new Map <String,Map<String,String>>();

//I need the popular map with these values

MapFist.put('FiestIndex', 'SecondIndex','Value');
```

Comment: What does "popular" mean to you in this context? Can you add some more description to your question of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to fill the map with the values ​​of the "put"
Note that in has three strings
I need to add the 3 within the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access each nested map level individually. Always make sure you initialize the inner layers before you attempt to use them (or you'll get a NullPointerException).

```
MapFist.put('FiestIndex', new Map<String, String>());
MapFist.get('FiestIndex').put('SecondIndex', 'Value');
```

Comment: I could do this dynamically

through a loop of repetition?

Comment: @Studentha Yes, you can. Just check for nulls first, if necessary.

Comment: Not to null these values ​​that you made with the put method will come from another map, it will be "one map inside another" haha

Comment: Are you in any material for me to refer to?

Comment: @Studentha https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/40310 is one such example of a multi-layer map populated dynamically. It's not quite the same as whatever you're doing, but close enough for practical purposes.

Comment: I thought of fz this through "for"